# How to get the current value if dropdownlist in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

`Dim zonename As String = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text`

It always display the first value from the dropdownlist

Comment: You mean something like array?

Comment: I m using dropdownlist in web page and in page_load event it is filled from sql database now i want to select the particular value from the list but after selecting the value and click on save_bt_event the above code always displays the first value of the dropdownlist

Comment: Did u try doing that with selectedvalue?

Comment: assing the value of dropdownlist to string in SelectedItem_changed() event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it binding in `is not postback`
[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

If you bind inside page load you will always get the first value of the dropdown list.

```
private void Page_Load()
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
        //bind your dropdown here
   }
}
```

In VB

```
Sub Page_Load
  If Not IsPostBack
    ' bind your dropdown list
    Validate()
  End If
End Sub
```

### Edit 1

Storing Connection string you can use web.config file

http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/store-connection-string-in-web-config

Comment: okay help me for another problem.... I want to use global page in vb.net for asp.net for my global variables like connection string, user sessions.... how to do this

Comment: Ideally you should put another question here. But You should use `web.config` for `connection-string` file for this. Also there is `gloabal.asax` which can help you.

Answer (score 0):

use page.ispostback

within page load event...

```
if NOT page.isPostBack Then
Dim zonename As String = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text
End if
```